# Reduce Array based on properties of 2 keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this.

```
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}]
```

I need to get an array like this:

```
var newData = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}]
```

That is get the highest value for each 'name' key in an array.

This is what I have tried:

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}]

console.log(data.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return (prev.name !== current.name && prev.value > current.value) ? prev : current
}))
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep track of the current highest `value` items for *every* `name`, so you could try reducing into an object, whose keys are the `name`s, and values are the currently winning `value`s for that name. Then, get the resulting object's values:

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}];

console.log(Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, item) => {
    const { name, value } = item;
    if (!a[name] || a[name].value < value) a[name] = item;
    return a;
  }, {})
));
```

(Your `prev.name !== current.name ...` method would only work if you're only trying to get *one* item out of it in the end - because you need more, you need an object that can contain multiple items.)

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce and check if the accumulator array has the same fruit using `findIndex` . If it is -1 , then in accumulator array push the value else update the count in that index

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}]



let result = data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {

  let findIfExist = acc.findIndex(elem => {
    return elem.name === curr.name;
  })
  if (findIfExist === -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    if (acc[findIfExist].value < curr.value) {
      acc[findIfExist].value = curr.value
    }

  }

  return acc;

}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` instead of `reduce`

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}]

let result = {};
data.forEach(function(current) {
  if (result[current.name] &&
    result[current.name].value < current.value &&
    result[current.name].category === current.category) {
    result[current.name].value = current.value;
  } else if (!result[current.name]) {
    result[current.name] = current;
  }
});
console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: is there any reason to use forEach instead of reduce ?

Comment: @brk No specific reason.. CertainPerformance answer looks great as well..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 12
}, {
  name: 'Apple',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 65
}, {
  name: 'Orange',
  category: 'Fruit',
  value: 40
}]
let result=data.reduce(function(temp, current) {
  //check if temp has object
  var found = temp.some((el) => {
      return el.name === current.name
    });
  //if not found, add the object
    if (!found) { temp.push(current) }
  //if found and value is greater, replace the max value
  else{
    temp.find((element) => {
     if(element.name === current.name && element.value<current.value)
    element.value=current.value
    })
  }
  return temp
},[])
console.log(result);
```